# How to write a script, which when ran increments the number by 1?

Tags: javascript, windows, scripting, increment, auto-increment

I am looking to write a script in windows which when the user clicks on it increments the count by 1.

The script has a variable integer 000000 
Another variable string number

When the user clicks on the script from their desktop it increments the integer to 000001 and appendes in front of number so it becomes number000001 and when user next clicks it increases to number000002 and so on.

I am sure it's a simple script but I am not sure where to begin or which language to use, it'll be great if someone can help me out

I think it would be something along the lines of, but not really sure what I am doing, how to save the increment from last run, how to run trigger the script when the icon is clicked from desktop.

```
Integer = 000000 
String = "Number"

Integer++ 

IntegerString = Number+Integer
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you need this 00000 before 1,2,3 and etc?
try this one:

```
let i = 0;
const s = 'Number';
const intString = s + format(i++);
```

and formatter for number:

```
 function format(num) {
     let strNum = num.toString();
     const numSize = strNum.length;
     for(i = numSize; i < 6; i++) {
        strNum = 0 + strNum;
     }
 }
```

Comment: The numerical value is in 6 digits so as the number increments to 10ths, 100th and so on position the 0 would be replaced but I would need the 000000 to begin with. Does your method execute the script when it is clicked on from desktop, save the previous increment and what language is this?

Comment: it's javascript language as you tagged you question with this language. If you need to save increment result you can save it into a file. Let say you can use nodejs with his FS module to save the last result and read it on execute.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into nodejs. Would this script execute at launch and what about the 00000 at the front as I am really looking for that to be incremented with each run.

Comment: i have update answer with formatter to add 00000 to your number

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this probably solves your problem

```js
let dv = "000000";
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 let increment = ++dv;
 increment = ("000000" + increment).slice(-6);
 document.querySelector('span').innerText = increment
})
```

```html
<button>increment</button>
<h1>number<span>000000</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks @Grzegorz T. Does this require a button to be pressed to increment, I am looking for something that should be excuted on launch of the script so say for example if in future I auto start the script on start-up it should increment without further interaction. Also does this solution save and retrieve the count at each run?

Comment: Just to add to the previous message, I understand I have indicated JS for the script but any scripting language would do, ideally I'd prefer something with least dependencies or modules to be installed, none would be preferred. Thanks.